# await client.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync not responding

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I want to perform face recognition in Unity using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face for the Hololens 2.

I basically followed this [Face Client Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/client-libraries?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-csharp) and tried using `await faceClient.Face.DetectWithUrlAsync` as well as `await faceClient.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync` with local images, but the program does not get past this line of code (no response at all, Unity also shows no response). However, when investigating the azure resources metrics, it shows successful calls and output data.
The only output I get in Visual Studio is "Loaded: Modul: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly".

This is the problematic code snippet:

```
using (Stream faceimagestream = File.OpenRead(filepath))
        {
            detectedFaces = await client.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(faceimagestream, returnFaceAttributes: features);
        }
```

Comment: As per the official documentation, Face recognition is possible in unity with hololens Gen 1. If there is any procedure that made you to follow regarding Gen2 kindly share those details also for better understanding the requirements.

Comment: There is indeed just one documentation for using the face client with the hololens 1 and a "quickstart" for using the client library in general. However, I thought it must somehow be possible to apply them to the hololens 2, as I read that at least one publication managed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `await` according to the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) instead of `method.Wait()`, which was used in the tutorial's example (which was obviously not built for Unity). The `Wait()` call blocks the whole thread, therefore Unity does not respond.